# Sockets in Ruby, how can I asynchronously read and write data through a Socket

Tags: ruby, sockets

I am trying to build a ruby based background job which is required to establish a TCP socket connection and keep reading from its stream.
I require the same socket to be open to write data.

I know the server behind the socket is working as expect as I have other services that can use it.

I tried to span a background thread, to keep reading the stream, but it never gets data

```
@socket = TCPSocket.new(localhost, 1234)


def read_data_loop
  while true
    @socket.each_line do |line|
      p "data: #{line}"
    end
  end
end

@buffer_thread = Thread.new { read_data_loop }

@socket.write("send me something!!")

sleep(10)
@buffer_thread.exit
```

I am craving for a working example to achieve this async read/write...

ps. I used `TCPSocket` in this example because it seamed like a good idea to start with, but I am not sold on it. I will take anything that works

Comment: `each_line` expects the line terminator `\n` (it uses `gets` internally). Does the server use the proper line terminator? I tried your code on my server (Linux Ubuntu), and it works fine, but you do have a bug with regards to disconnecting and reconnecting. So without knowing if the problem is with the disco/reco, or the line terminator, it's hard to give further guidance.

Comment: arg... that might be it. what is a non-blocking reader?

Comment: You don't need non-blocking if you just know the line terminator. You can run the loop with any terminator, just supply the terminator to `each_line` (see docs for how). Non-blocking would mean you manage all the nitty gritty details of reading from the socket yourself, including buffering. It means no `read` calls will block, and you would need to use methods like `select` to check the socket for data. It will increase code complexity, so I don'r recommend that approach if possible.

Comment: this is for a endless stream of serial data

Comment: and I already have a  data-carrier class which bundles up the messages of this peculiar protocol. I will try the `select` now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Casper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823617/casper)'s recommendation in the question comments, I changed the proc to use `IO.select`. It worked as a breese.

The first thing to know is that attempting to read the socket (`@socket.recv`) when there is no data in its buffer will make the socket "hang" waiting for a new message from the server. This has the the annoying side effect of preventing us from writing to the socket (via separated thread).
So to fix this, the `IO.select` call would try to read the socked for 2 seconds (the 2 used as last parameter below). When the 2s elapse without data, `IO.select` returns `nil` which allowed me to not call `@socket.recv` when we know it would "hang".

A great side effect is that my `while true` does not kill the client when there is no data, as `IO.select` takes 2s to timeout on each loop.

This is the end result:

```
@socket = TCPSocket.new(localhost, 1234)


def read_data_loop
  while true
    while IO.select([@socket], nil, nil, 2) && (line = @socket.recv(50))
        p line
    end
  end
end

@buffer_thread = Thread.new { read_data_loop }

@socket.write("send me something!!")

sleep(10)
@buffer_thread.exit
```

This made the background thread write to the console:

```
server response
hi there
```

as these were two messages I had set up on the server.